# Family of probability distribution closed under addition and conditioning on being less/greater than a threshold

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is there a sensible family of probability distribution with the following properties:

- If distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are in the family with $X$ and $Y$ being independent, then so is the distribution of $X + Y$.
- If distributions of $X$ is in the family then so is the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X < t$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$
- If distributions of $X$ is in the family then so is the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X > t$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$

There are obvious answers such as an empty family and the family of all probability distributions but I'm looking for a fairly small but sufficiently complex example. Ideally it should be parametrized by couple of real parameters that would allow to control for mean and standard deviation.

Uniform distribution is almost ideal but the first point is violated as the sums are horrible. Shifted exponentials also play nicely with the third point and give OK result with the first point but still, the resulting Erlang distribution wouldn't play as nice with the third point and this time the second condition is problematic.

It doesn't have to be discrete but again, binomial and Poisson also have multiple problems fulfilling the above (essentially, because of the second and third point, the family should have examples of supports from any interval).

Is there any way to get all three of them? If so, how far do we have to go?

Comment: Should the first point hold even when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent? I feel like in that case, it is a very demanding condition. Moreover that will probably not help you but you can consider the family of finitely supported measures, or the family of compactly supported measures, or the family of distributions which have an at most countable support, or the family of all probability distributions on $\mathbb R_+$...

Comment: @Will I meant independent variables, thank you.